# create array by removing infinity

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I need to create an array with numpy in python with the following conditions.

```
distances = np.array ([0, .3,4])

def _distance_weights(self, distances):
    return np.array([(1/y,y) for d, y in np.ndenumerate(distances)])
```

it gives me the result:

```
 [[inf 0.]
 [3.33333333 0.3]
 [0.25 4.]]
```

I do not know how to do it so that when it's infinite I do not do the function. I should give the following result

```
 [[1 0.]
 [3.33333333 0.3]
 [0.25 4.]]
```

Thank you and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code at the source of the infinity to stop it from ever being added to your list:

```
distances = np.array ([0, .3,4])

def _distance_weights(self, distances):
    return np.array([(1 if y == 0 else 1/y,y) for d, y in np.ndenumerate(distances)])
```

If you've never seen the `if` syntax like that before, here's how it works:
`1 if y == 0 else 1/y` will evaluate to `1` if `y == 0`, otherwise it will evaluate to `1/y`.

Is `1` the best choice for the replacement to `infinity` though? I would probably use `-1` myself - especially since I don't think your distances will never be negative.